# how can I use scrapy to extract data from webpage that has a database

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

Hello I am using scrapy to accessing our intranet website and do some scraping, everything seems to be working I am able to access it, but when I am extracting data into a csv file the csv file is empty i get no errors when i run this. Each column (Directory Number, Equipment ID, Subscriber ID and etc...)from the HTML has data so how can i get that data with scrapy.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from carrier.items import CarrierItem

class CarrierSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'dis'
    allowed_domains = ['qvpweb01.ciq.labs.att.com']
    login_page = 'https://qvpweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/login.jsp'
    start_urls = ["https://qvpweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/"]

    def init_request(self):
    #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
    return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
    #"""Generate a login request."""
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'txtUserName': 'xxxx', 'txtPassword': 'secret'},
            callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
    #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
    if "logout" in response.body:
        self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
        # Now the crawling can begin..

        return self.initialized() 

    else:
        self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad password :(\n\n\n")
        # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

    def parse(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n We got data! \n\n\n")
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//form[@id=\'listForm\']/table/')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = CarrierItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('thead/th/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('thead/th/a/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

html from page

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">
<html>
<html>
<div class="clr"></div>
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" colspan="2">
<div class="list">
<form id="listForm" name="listForm" method="POST" action="">
<table>
<thead>
<th class="first"></th>
<th>
<a href="/dis/?&orderby=mdn&order=asc">Directory Number</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="/dis/?&orderby=hardwareId&order=asc">Equipment ID</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="/dis/?&orderby=subscriberId&order=asc">Subscriber ID</a>
</th>
<th class="arrow_up">
<th>
<a href="/dis/?&orderby=sessUpldTime&order=asc">Session Upload Time</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="/dis/?&orderby=upldRsn&order=asc">Upload Reason</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="/dis/?&orderby=prof&order=asc">Profile ID</a>
</th>
<th>
<img width="1" height="1" src="/dis/img/spacer.gif" alt="">
</th>
<th class="last">
<img width="1" height="1" src="/dis/img/spacer.gif" alt="">
</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

output when I run the crawler

```
C:\Users\ye831c\Documents\Big Data\Scrapy\carrier>scrapy crawl dis -o iqDis.csv
-t csv
2013-06-28 14:10:41-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: carrier)
2013-06-28 14:10:41-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogSt
ats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAut
hMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, De
faultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMi
ddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMi
ddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddle
ware
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [dis] INFO: Spider opened
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [dis] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0
 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:602
3
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [dis] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://qvpweb01.ciq.la
bs.att.com:8080/dis/login.jsp> (referer: None)
2013-06-28 14:10:42-0500 [dis] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://qvpweb01
.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/> from <POST https://qvpweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/d
is/login>
2013-06-28 14:10:43-0500 [dis] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://qvpweb01.ciq.la
bs.att.com:8080/dis/> (referer: https://qvpweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/login
.jsp)
2013-06-28 14:10:43-0500 [dis] DEBUG:


    Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!



2013-06-28 14:10:44-0500 [dis] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://qvpweb01.ciq.la
bs.att.com:8080/dis/> (referer: https://qvpweb01.ciq.labs.att.com:8080/dis/)
2013-06-28 14:10:44-0500 [dis] DEBUG:


     We got data!



2013-06-28 14:10:44-0500 [dis] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-06-28 14:10:44-0500 [dis] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 1382,
     'downloader/request_count': 4,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 146604,
     'downloader/response_count': 4,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 28, 19, 10, 44, 469000),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 12,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'request_depth_max': 2,
     'response_received_count': 3,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 28, 19, 10, 42, 15000)}
2013-06-28 14:10:44-0500 [dis] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

C:\Users\ye831c\Documents\Big Data\Scrapy\carrier>
```

Comment: Is that the html you see in your browser or what you got from your scrape?

Comment: Never mind. alecxe has the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your xpath expressions, they should be relative (`.//`):

```
item['title'] = site.select('.//thead/th/a/text()').extract()
item['link'] = site.select('.//thead/th/a/@href').extract()
```

UPDATE:

After discussing the problem in chat, found that the page that scrapy receives is an xml that is converted using js after the page load.

Here's what helped to parse the xml to get necessary data:

```
def parse(self, response):
    xhs = XmlXPathSelector(response)

    columns = hxs.select('//table[3]/header/column'')
    for column in columns:
        item = CarrierItem()
        item['title'] = column.select('.//text()').extract()
        item['link'] = column.select('.//@uri').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: adding (.//) to both title and link xpath I get an error           File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\sel
ector\lxmlsel.py", line 47, in select
            raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % xpath)
        exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //form[@id='listForm']/table/

Comment: Sure, slash at the end: replace `sites = hxs.select('//form[@id=\'listForm\']/table/')` with `sites = hxs.select('//form[@id=\'listForm\']/table')`.

Comment: i did not get no errors but nothing gets display in my csv file. In my csv I would get the column name and links right or just the data

Comment: Well, everything else looks ok. Could you check if it actually finds smth using `//form[@id="listForm"]/table` xpath?

Comment: ok I changed it to //form[@id="listForm"]/table and nothing seems to be working i get the same result no errors but nothing gets output

Comment: There is one more possible scenario: your content is loaded via ajax call after the page load. Please, use browser developer tools to see what requests are going on during the page load.

Comment: how can I use the browser developer tool?

Comment: Is it possible this may be the reason that it has javascript in my html <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> Carrier IQ DIS 2.4 :: All Devices</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dis/js/main.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dis/js/validate.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dis/css/portal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dis/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
</head>

Comment: If you are using chrome, press `ctrl+shift+j` and open network tab. In firefox, use `firebug`.

Comment: oh yes I've been using firebug in firefox

Comment: hey @alecxe can you take a look at this one also [scrapy question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17413886/2475251)

Comment: The problem there might be related. Have you checked if the page is loaded via js dynamically? You can use `print response.body` in your `parse` method and see if you really see the same html you've provided.

Comment: I did the print response.body and it worked i got the data from the start_urls were i want to extract the data ex.        <cell type="href" href="/dis/sessions.jsp?view=list&amp;device_gid=48563
7724556736A77785A7A554D584E6E5241774F773D3D&amp;hwdid=004402340380640&amp;mdn=&a
mp;subscrbid=&amp;maxlength=100">view sessions</cell>
        <cell type="href" href="/dis/errors_agg.jsp?view=list&amp;device_gid=485
637724556736A77785A7A554D584E6E5241774F773D3D&amp;hwdid=004402340380640&amp;mdn=
&amp;subscrbid=&amp;maxlength=100">view errors</cell>
    </row>
</table>
<rowsNumberLimited value="false"/>

Comment: My above comment the output from  **print response.body** in the parse method, the html  is different from the html i see when i use firebug. This one has <cell type> the one in firebug doesn't have <cell type>

Comment: I checked the page source in firefox and that is what is getting printing out when i do a print response.body its the xml-stylesheet not the html i see in firebug

Comment: Thanks Alecxe your awesome!!